# Como fazer o ORDER BY com uma informação que possa variar?

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, sql-select

Estou pegando uma lista de artigos de um banco de dados e quero ter na página uma
ferramenta que me permita listá-los por ordem de data que foram escritos ou por ordem alfabética.

Aqui tenho minha função de leitura do banco:

```
$sel = DBRead('artigos', null ,'*', 'ORDER BY data ASC');
```

Se deixo `data` a listagem é feita começando pela postagem mais antiga, se eu mudar para `nome` a listagem é feita por ordem alfabética.

Eu construí um formulário no HTML com um "select"
e dois "options" dentro e através do método POST consigo pegar o valor de um desses 
    "option's" e colocar na variável `$mudanca`.

Mas se eu colocar a variável na função de leitura dá erro:

```
$sel = DBRead('artigos', null ,'*', 'ORDER BY $mudanca ASC');
```

Alguma sugestão diferente?

**Acrescento algo que pode ser útil a alguém que esteja construindo a mesma coisa:**

```
 <?php 
  $mudanca="data";
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 $mudanca = $_POST['mudar'];
 }   
 ?>
```

Ou seja, deixe uma variável padrão setada, pois antes do método post ser acionado **$mudanca** estaria vazia causando erro no **ORDER BY $mudanca**.

Comment: Outra opção seria `$sel = DBRead('artigos', null ,'*', 'ORDER BY ' . $mudanca . ' ASC');` Considere mais lento interpretar uma variável dentro de strings.

Comment: Eu pensei nisso, mas na hora coloquei as aspas de forma errada, então não funcionou... :(

Comment: [Vale a pena dar uma lida nessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/1244639)

Comment: Pelo que li o "heredoc" substitue as aspas duplas e ainda dispensa o uso de "escape", mas por que não vejo ele sendo usado?

Comment: @IWannaKnow heredoc é raramente usado, só em caso muitos específicos (que até hoje não achei nenhum) que ele deve ser usado. Na maioria dos casos aspas duplas/simples são o suficiente.

Comment: @IWannaKnow por exemplo, imagine você colocando `heredoc` nesse código, além da estética horrível, seria na minha opinião sem precisão nenhuma, no seu código poderia ser concatenação ou aspas duplas!

Comment: O link é uma explicação sobre aspas simples e duplas, não me referi a Heredoc ou Nowdoc. Os dois ultimos tem suas utilidades, mas não convém ao caso da questão.

Comment: Não me mostre coisa nova não que fico curioso... valeu!

Comment: @PapaCharlie eu também achava que aspas duplas tinha o processamento mais lento, e resolvi fazer um teste de performance, e fiquei pasmo ao ver que usar `"texto $variavel texto"` é mais rápido que `'texto ' . $variavel . ' texto'` em todos os testes...

Comment: @I Wanna Know, mostrei a questão por conter sua duvida (aspas simples e aspas duplas)... Nem tudo que se lê vale o teste, mas é sempre bom saber o que há disponível.

Comment: @Jader, o desempenho das aspas é consenso e a perda não é significativa - mas existe. Há vários fatores que podem alterar o resultado de um BENCH. [Aqui tem um debate com alguns testes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13620/1244639). Até queria saber como chegou nessa conclusão, mas acho que sai da questão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloque assim:

```
$sel = DBRead('artigos', null ,'*', "ORDER BY $mudanca ASC");
```

Ou seja, aspas duplas!

Dentro de aspas simples o PHP não interpreta nada ele coloca aquilo que está nela como um texto somente, enquanto que em aspas duplas se tiver variáveis PHP por exemplo ele vai interpreta e te mostrar o resultado.

```
$texto = 'imprime texto';
echo '$texto'; // saída -> $texto
echo "$texto"; // saída -> imprime texto
```

***Exemplo Online:*** [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/EzhVla)

*Ou*

**Concatenação**

```
$sel = DBRead('artigos', null ,'*', 'ORDER BY '.$mudanca.' ASC');
```

[**Boa leitura.**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php)

Comment: `**$mudanca**` acho que era pra sair negrito, não? Também pode ser "{$mudanca}" como padrão usas-se as chaves para marcar a saida de uma variável

Comment: Muito obrigado @Maria, a cada dia percebo que programação não é só saber a lógica, tem que se atentar aos detalhes a todo tempo. Eu elaborei a parada toda e por causa de uma aspa não estava funcionando. Valeu!

Comment: Era Papa: tentei colocar negrito aqui no stack, mas já tirei, não funciona nos códigos. É, minhas funções de banco de dados estão entre chaves. Valeu!

Comment: @PapaCharlie as chaves também são vão ter efeito em aspas duplas, só lembrando ..., aspas simples terá o efeito de texto!

Comment: Por nada @IWannaKnow ...!